# Number of roots of $f(x)=x^2-2^{x-\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

How many roots does $f(x)=x^2-2^{x-\frac{1}{x}}$ have in $(0,1]$?
Since this function is continuous, I plugged in a couple of values and looked at the signs of the function's values and I concluded that there is a root between $\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{1}{5}$.$1$ is also a root, so I believe there are two roots in $(0,1]$, but how to rigorously prove this?

Comment: Your function has two roots in the given interval.

Comment: I believe it does, but how to prove this?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at it through Taylor series to prove there are only two roots. Plotting on Mathematica "confirms" your guess, but looking at the derivative directly seems to be rather complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of finding the roots $x^2 = 2^{x - 1/x}$, let's consider the roots of $f(x) = 2 \ln x - (x - 1/x) \ln 2$. We have
$$f'(x) = -\frac {\ln 2} {x^2} \left( x^2 - \frac {2 x} {\ln 2} + 1 \right).$$
$f'(x)$ has two positive roots the product of which is $1$, therefore it has exactly one root $x_0$ on $(0, 1)$.

This means that $f$ decreases from $\infty$ to $f(x_0)$ on $(0, x_0)$ and increases from $f(x_0)$ to $f(1) = 0$ on $(x_0, 1)$. Since $f(1) = 0$, we have $f(x_0) < 0$. Therefore $f$ has exactly two roots on $(0, 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Compute $$f(0.2),f(0.4)$$ and $$f(1)$$

Comment: That is exactly what I did, this shows that there are $2$ roots, but it doesn't imply there is not a third one.

Comment: Then show that the derivative between two points is decreasing

Comment: And how does this help? Is there any general result?

Comment: If it is so, then can the function cut the x-axes only one times since you have a sign change